# Git conflicts in pull requests

Tags: github, merge-conflict-resolution

I have 2 branches - `master` and `develop`

I have been doing some pull requests in my `develop` branch where it contains 5 items, in which it is the same as the number of items in `master`.

However, someone did some commits and `pushed` in a few more items into the `master` branch, and hence now it has 8 items.

As my pull request in the `develop` is still not yet approved/merged, whenever I tried to update my pull request, I am getting the message stating that `This pull request can't be merged. You will need to resolve conflicts to be able to merge` and asked me to do the following:

```
git fetch origin master
git checkout develop 
git merge FETCH_HEAD
git commit
git push origin HEAD
```

And this happens after I have 'pushed' out my commits, making me confused at times. Then I realized that it is asking me to re-add and re-commit in the additional 3 new items. So does this means I must ensure that the items and contents between these 2 branches of mine should be the same as always? I have always used `git pull/fetch` but will there be a better way for me to make sure?

Comment: No, it is asking you to merge. You seem to be confused about how branches work -- see the [related chapter in the docs](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching)

Comment: @remram Probably I am indeed confused. But even so, why would it ask me to merge the master onto develop? Usually it is the other way round for me

Comment: If you merge master in develop, then github will be able to automatically merge develop in master.

Comment: @remram Hmm, okay.. Still do not get it why I must merge master to develop.. So this means that I need to have the same number of items in both master and develop branch so as to prevent such conflicts in the future?

Comment: You don't *need* to do anything. Github will just tell you whether these branches can be merged automatically or not. If they can't, you'll just have to merge the PR from the command-line instead of the website when the time comes, and that's it.

Comment: We call the merge from master back to develop a "back merge".  This will synchronize the 2 branches to a point where the changes on develop can be merged up to master.  This happens a lot where there are a large number of developers making simultaneous changes to the project.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

What this means is that GitHub would like to merge your PR branch into `master`, but it can't, because there are conflicts. As you've discussed in the question comments, the best way to deal with this (usually) is to merge your `master` branch into `develop` on the command line. That will show you the conflicts and ask you to resolve them. Once you've completed and pushed that merge, the PR will be mergeable back into `master` using the green button on GitHub.

You *could* simply merge your `deploy` branch into `master` (which I realize sounds a bit more sensible). In that case, you'd be bypassing the PR entirely. You'd have to close the PR "unmerged", and separately you'd manually push the merge commit to `master`.

By doing it the first way,

1. you make a better audit trail by merging to master on GitHub, using the PR;
2. you give your team a chance to review your code after the merge, before it lands on `master`; and
3. if you have automatic tests (such as Travis CI or CircleCI) which check PRs, you give them a chance to run your merged code as well.

Comment: It has sort of making sense to me then, especially in the case of the PR branch, in which it would be totally different from what I have been doing where my `develop` branch is being merged into `master` just like what you have mentioned.

Comment: That's right. If you've got a single `develop` branch that periodically merges to `master`, you'd probably do better not to make pull requests from that branch. If you like, you can make pull requests from specific topic branches to `deploy`, and then merge `deploy` to `master` at the command line when you're ready to move a set of changes over.

Comment: This link gives a good overview of how to achieve Peeja's statement of merging master into develop: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/resolve-merge-conflicts-704414003.html